# Audio file is play late after write in buffer in android Audio Tack

Tags: java, android, audio, buffer, audiotrack

when i increase the size of buffer the audio sound that will write on buffer is play late.And when i discrease  the size of buffer the file is played correctly means the file is play on time not late. any one can help ... The buffer size is 64k.

```
public class MediaSPK
{
    private static final int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 16000;
    private static final int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO;
    private static final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

    VaxSIPUserAgent m_objVaxSIPUserAgent;

    boolean m_bMuteSpk = false;
    boolean m_bPlay = false;

    AudioTrack m_objAudioTrack = null;

    public MediaSPK(VaxSIPUserAgent objVaxSIPUserAgent)
    {
        m_objVaxSIPUserAgent = objVaxSIPUserAgent;
    }

    public void OpenSpk() 
    {
        int nMinBuffSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);

        //Log.i("size SPK", "" + m_nMinBuffSize);

        m_objAudioTrack = new  AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, 64000, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
        m_objAudioTrack.play();

        m_bPlay = false;
    }

    public void PlaySpk(byte[] aData, int nDataSize)
    {
        if(m_bMuteSpk)
        {
            byte[] aDataSilence = new byte[nDataSize];
            m_objAudioTrack.write(aDataSilence, 0, nDataSize);
        }
        else
        {
            m_objAudioTrack.write(aData, 0, nDataSize);
        }
    }

    public void Mute(boolean bEnable)
    {
        //m_bMuteSpk = bEnable;

        //m_objAudioTrack
    }

    public void CloseSpk() 
    {
        if(m_objAudioTrack == null)
            return;

        try 
        {
            m_objAudioTrack.stop();
            m_objAudioTrack.release();
            m_objAudioTrack = null;
        } 
        catch (IllegalStateException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you are putting the whole operation on the single thread try to split out the operation play the audio in a seperate thread by using

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();

mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable(), delay);
```

Comment: plz give any other reason that might be possible

Comment: can u explain why i can create any separate thread to play a file